# How to use member variables with Interfaces and anonymous implementations

Tags: java, interface, anonymous-class

Please check the Java code below:

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String arg[]) throws Throwable
  {
      Test t = new Test();
      System.out.println(t.meth().s);           //OP: Old value
      System.out.println(t.meth().getVal());    //OP: String Implementation
  }
  private TestInter meth()
  {
    return new TestInter()
    {
      public String s = "String Implementation";
      public String getVal()
      {
        return this.s;
      }
    };
  }
}
interface TestInter
{
  String s = "Old value";
  String getVal();
}
```

As you see I have created an interface anonymously. When I access the interface variable directly, it will show "Old value".

t.meth().s     =>   "Old value"

Accessing it through the getVal() method returns proper values,

t.meth().getVal()     =>   "String Implementation"

I don't understand how this code works, can somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `s` variable declared in the interface is *entirely separate* from the `s` variable you've declared in your anonymous inner class.

Interface variables are really just designed to be constants - they aren't part of the API each implementation needs to provide. In particular, they're implicitly static and final.

From the [JLS section 9.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3):

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.

The fact that you've accessed the field via an implementation instance is irrelevant - this code:

```
System.out.println(t.meth().s);
```

is effectively:

```
t.meth();
System.out.println(TestInter.s);
```

I would strongly encourage you to avoid using variables in interfaces *except* for genuine constants... and even then, only where it really makes sense. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but declaring a field in an interface isn't a good way forward IMO.

Comment: You would *discourage the use* or *recommend to avoid* variables in interfaces, right?

Comment: @JonSkeet but even though he extends a normal class instead of an interface, he gets the same results. I tested it. am I correct, that's what I have framed in my answer... please correct me if I'm wrong... thanks:)

Comment: @pinkpanther: Yes, you get the same results but for a slightly different reason. You're absolutely right that there's no variable-overriding - there would still be two different variables - but it's even *worse* with the interface version as the field is implicitly static.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like `variable-overriding` like `method overriding` in java. Name a new type for `subclass`, then you will get the `"String Implementation"`, when you access through the subclass reference type.

Access privilege `protected` only means we can access the variable in a subclass but not that it can be override.

Even if you are using normal `class` instead of `interface` this won't work. When you refer using `super` class type, you only get the `instance` variables from `super` type and so on....
This example illustrates the first case:
Example:

```
public class Tester
{
  public static void main(String arg[]) throws Throwable
  {
      Tester t = new Tester();
      System.out.println(t.meth().s); // it prints "Old value" because your type is TestInter           
  }
  private TestInter meth()
  {
    return new TestInter()
    {
       protected String s = "String Implementation";

    };
  }
}
class TestInter
{
  protected String s = "Old value";

}
```

This example illustrates the second case:
 It prints `"String Implementation"`

```
 public class Tester
{
  public static void main(String arg[]) throws Throwable
  {
      Tester t = new Tester();
      System.out.println(t.meth().s);           
  }
  private SubTestInter meth()
  {
    return new SubTestInter();
  }
}
class SubTestInter extends TestInter{
       protected String s = "String Implementation";
}
class TestInter
{
  protected String s = "Old value";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
When i access a interface variable directly
```

You have the reference of Interface type, that's why it refers to interface directly and you get "Old value"

```
Accessing getVal() method, showing proper values
```

When you invoke method getVal() you refer to actual implementation of this method and that's why getVal of actual implementation is called. This means current instance with the following value:

```
public String s = "String Implementation";
```

Answer (score 1):

Fields declared in an interface are constants.

Thus, when writing

```
interface TestInter
{
  String s = "Old value";
  String getVal();
}
```

You are declaring a constant s.
That's why `t.meth().s` is printing `Old value`

`t.meth().getVal()` is printing the content of the field `s` of your anonymous class.